# 35mm and 35mm-film tags

Tags: discussion

I noticed there are tags for [35mm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm) and [35mm-film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm-film).  The latter obviously refers to the film format, and many, if not most, of the questions tagged with 35mm are to do with 35mm focal length lenses.

I created a tag wiki for 35mm to clarify it was for lens questions (I assume it is anyway), and was going to move a few 35mm film questions tagged with [35mm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm) to [35mm-film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm-film).  There are a few more than I thought, and now I wonder if this is pointless?

Could also rename 35mm to 35mm-lens I suppose.   Is it a waste of time trying to adjust these things, or worse, am I going to cause any problems doing it?

Edit: having thought about it, I do think changing 35mm to [35mm-lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm-lens) would be good.  When people tag questions they'd see 35mm-lens and 35mm-film and could make an informed choice, and it would help in searching to have two clear tags.

If that's agreeable, is it possible to rename/migrate a tag??  I don't want to create 35mm-lens and then move a bunch of questions over - could mess up all sorts of favorites, badges, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds good. You can basically just do it, by retaggging. The two downsides are:

1. A lot of work for you
2. A lot of churn on the front page.

#1 I don't care about either way. :) With #2, I try to go back and look at newer questions which were pushed down by any such activity and add a new answer or make a constructive edit, so they're not penalized in visibility by the housekeeping.

A mod would then need to make 35mm an alias of 35mm-lens, which sounds reasonable to me given the rationale you've given.

Comment: If 35mm is made an alias (synonym?) of 35mm-lens, then can new questions still be tagged with either?  Or does 35mm become sort of inactive?

Comment: The would mean that when someone uses 35mm, it is automatically remapped to 35mm-lens. Then, someone theoretically will notice that and fix it if that's not what was meant. (There may also be a way to kill tags completely, but I'm not aware of it.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at how many of each tag exist and see if it's worth doing after all. Won't do a big bulk update.

Comment: Might also be worth renaming [tag:50mm] to [tag:50mm-lens]. \*shrug\*

Comment: There are plenty more.  filter is used for lens filters and PP effects, i.e. photoshop plugins...

Answer (score 2):

Do we really need a tag for [35mm-lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/35mm-lens)? (or any other prime length?)

What could be asked that would require specific knowledge of that focal length, that wouldn't apply to others? I'd have thought it would be better to de-tag those that aren't about film photography, and merge the two tags as synonyms (obviously after updating the tag wiki accordingly)

Comment: maybe retag with [lens] [wide-angle] or something?  Sounds a better idea actually.

Comment: Well, they're wide angle lenses in some questions and normal lenses in others....

Comment: There were three questions that referred to the focal length, and many more referring to the film format, so have merged 35mm-film and 35mm